# How to allow external custom domains to run a Laravel app on my server?

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx, cloudflare, forge

My app is a Laravel app, running on Nginx, provisioned by Forge, and SSL certificates are provided by CloudFlare.

It is hosted at a URL like https://www.myapp.com

My app’s customers are businesses, and already own their domains:

```
https://www.customer1.com
https://www.customer2.com
https://www.customer3.com
etc.
```

I want my customers to run MyApp from the sub-domains of their choice:

```
https://some-name.customer1.com
https://some-other-name.customer2.com
https://any-name-they-want.customer3.com
etc.
```

My customers should ***not*** install anything — MyApp still runs on myapp.com, not on their servers

My customers should ***only*** (if possible) modify their DNS, probably add a CNAME like "some-name” that points to “myapp.com”

I followed this amazing article: [Dynamic custom domain routing in Laravel](https://medium.com/@joelennon/dynamic-custom-domain-routing-in-laravel-62c5ffec666b).

but I can't get it to work in an https (with SSL) environment -- the browser returns:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
some-name.customer1.com uses an unsupported protocol.

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

How should Nginx and/or SSL certificates be configured?

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/

Comment: How did you finally proceed? Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is still a question which is not very simple.

However, Caddy does generate SSLs automatically (if replacing Nginx with Caddy is an option for you).

You can check the documentation for more.